# Не выполняется sql запрос

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
    String authentication = "SELECT Email,Password FROM Mailbox_Users " +
            "WHERE \"Email\" = ? AND \"Password\" = ?";
    try {
        conn = OracleDAOFactory.createConnection();
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(authentication);
        statement.setString(1,email);
        statement.setString(2,password);
        System.out.println(statement.toString());
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
            tableEmail = rs.getString("Email");
            tablePass = rs.getString("Password");
        }
    } finally {
        assert statement != null;
        statement.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

Почему то после строки где мы делаем выполнение, ничего с базы не вытаскивается, а сразу переходит в блок finally.
Все данные есть и имена прописаны правильно.

Comment: Запрос очень странный. В  списке выборки поля Email и Password не заключены в кавычки, что в Oracle равнозначно названиям полей полностью большими буквами (EMAIL, PASSWORD), а далее в фразе where они заключены в двойные кавычки, т.е. в БД ищутся поля в том виде как написаны, т.е. маленькими с большой. Посмотрите структуру таблицы и расставьте/уберите кавычки и/или напишите имена полей в правильном регистре. А вообще запросы надо перед тем как писать в программу проверять в средствах разработки БД. Ну и ошибки наверное надо у БД получать и выводить (если конечно ваш язык это сам не делает)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51298/discussion-on-question-by-sasuke---sql-).